# What code allows me to have this syntax ClassName<datatype>()

Tags: c#, generics

I noticed that the Ninject API has calls such as

```
Bind<ISomething>().DoSomethingElse();
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: It's not a `ClassName<DataType>`. It's a `MethodName<DataType>` in this case. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to invoke it with `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called method chaining. This achieved by building methods that are returing the same instances.

simple example

```
interface test
{
     test bind();
     test  DoSomethingElse();
}

class tester:test
{
    test bind()
    { 
         // blah 
    }

    test DoSomethingElse()
    { 
         // blah 
    }
}

tester obj = new tester()
obj.bind().DoSomethingElse()
```

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy, did you check the OP's exact question. he asked Bind().DoSomethingElse(); pls check out the initial version.......

Comment: The question subject line asked about the `<>`, not what happens after it.  (And for the record, wasn't my downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx).

In your specific example, it is a [Generic Method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28VS.80%29.aspx)

The idea is that you only have to write one generic method signature which you can use for any type (as long as you don't restrict it).

Take the generic `List<T>` for example. You can create it to hold any type: string, int, classes, structs, whichever you like. If it wasn't generic, you'd have to write specific code for all of the types it can contain, or everything would have to be boxed to an object, like with the `ArrayList` class, which comes at a performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that `Bind` is a generic method which takes a single type parameter. It's signature would look like the following

```
public T Bind<T>() {
  ...
}
```

So calling `Bind<ISomething>()` calls the function with a bound type parameter of `ISomething` and returns an `ISomething` instance.

Note: I don't know if this is the actual signature of the function.  Not familiar with Ninject in particular but speculating based on other APIs

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic method defined on the [`BindingRoot`](http://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Syntax/BindingRoot.cs) class.

```
public IBindingToSyntax<T> Bind<T>() 
{
    ...
}
```